# C compiling error with shellforge

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shellforge

l made a C program and l want to compile it using shell forge but I had several errors, how can I solve them?

Errors

```
##[ERROR]## compiler reported error 1 while compiling /tmp/sfvLvXlY/sonu.c
##[ERROR]## In file included from :1:
././sflib/linux_amd64/sflib.h:93: warning: "struct rusage" declared inside parameter list
././sflib/linux_amd64/sflib.h:93: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
././sflib/linux_amd64/sflib.h:97: warning: "struct sembuf" declared inside parameter list
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:34,
                 from /tmp/sfvLvXlY/sonu.c:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/include/stddef.h:213: error: conflicting types for 'size_t'
././sflib/linux_amd64/../common/sftypes.h:25: error: previous declaration of 'size_t' was here
```

Comment: Can you please show some source?

Comment: You can see the codes at this website, l guess i have to write tis code without external libraries and related commands to this libraries,but l dont know how l can do that. https://forum.ceviz.net/c-c/131986-c-programi-acil-yardim.html